# How to use simulated object from Synbreed package in the Optisel package in R

Tags: r, dataframe, package

I'm very new with R and currently working on a simple simulation. I am creating a pedigree-structure (data frame) and editing it in order to do some simple calculations.
I am using 2 different packages:

1. `Synbreed`, which simulates a pedigree data frame
2. `Optisel`, which allows calculations with pedigree structures

The problem I have is as follows: once I have created the data frame with the pedigree with synbreed, I loaded the optiSel. After I do this and try to change or calculate something with the data frame, all the values within the data frame will disappear/become NA...

I want to make a for-loop with these functions, so I need to make sure they are compatible. Weirdly enough, the script does work when I save the data frame, close R and import the simulated data frame again.

Here I have the simple script:

#### Start script

`library(synbreed)`

`ped.test<-simul.pedigree(generations=10,ids=10,animals=T)` #create the pedigree data frame

the data frame needs some small edits:

```
ped.test$Par1[ped.test$Par1==0]<-NA
ped.test$Par2[ped.test$Par2==0]<-NA
ped.test$sex[ped.test$sex==1]<-2
ped.test$sex[ped.test$sex==0]<-1
```

The data frame is a pedigree structure:

```
class(ped.test)
```

`library(optiSel)` #Load the optiSel package, all is going well

```
colnames(ped.test)<-c("Indiv", "Sire", "Dam", "Born", "Sex")
```

#### Now above I only wanted to change to column names, not even with a function from the optiSel package, but the data.frame values will disappear.

```
ped.test
```

#### End script

From the optiSel package I need the following function to work:

`pedig<-prePed(ped.test)`

This needs the changes shown above in order to accept the pedigree structure, but it won't work as the newly created pedigree structured is empty.

Comment: I tried with the synbreed version 0.12.6 and by using the example provided with the simul.pedigree function, simulated data frame was empty (Pedigree object with 0 subjects and Bit size= 0 ). By using your code, I was able to change column names, but the point is that the ped.test is empty anyway and I do not know why... Is there any additional step that needs to be performed prior to simulation? Nevertheless, try to load packages in a row (one after the other), and/or try to load first optiSel and then synbreed...

Comment: Thanks for trying. There are no steps prior to the simulation. When I open R (so no other packages have been turned on) and do the simul.breed function, I can get a complete data.frame.

I tried loading the packages in a row or optiSel first, but both of these attempts resulted in emty data frames.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the code you provided with the package `synbreed` (v.0.12.6) and package `optiSel` (v.0.9.1).

The point is that the function `simul.pedigree` from the `synbreed` package returns an object of class `"pedigree"` and `"data.frame"` and `prePed` function from the `optiSel` package requires an object of class `data.frame` (try `?prePed`).

So, you can re-assign the class of the `ped.test` as *just* a `data.frame`:

```
library(synbreed)

packageVersion("synbreed")

ped.test<-synbreed::simul.pedigree(generations=10,ids=10,animals=T)

ped.test

ped.test$Par1[ped.test$Par1==0]<-NA
ped.test$Par2[ped.test$Par2==0]<-NA
ped.test$sex[ped.test$sex==1]<-2
ped.test$sex[ped.test$sex==0]<-1

class(ped.test)

class(ped.test) <- "data.frame" # this is the missing step!

library(optiSel)

colnames(ped.test)<-c("Indiv", "Sire", "Dam", "Born", "Sex")

pedig<-prePed(ped.test)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a simple solution!